# Phonegap Ajax Post Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, post, phonegap-build

I have been searching high and low to come up with a solution to an error I am getting with a phonegap app I am building.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="app-send" name="app-send">
        <input id="a" name="a" type="text">
        <input id="b" name="b" type="text">
        <input id="c" name="c" type="text">
        <input id="timestamp" name="timestamp" type="text">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#app-send').submit(function (e) {
                var postData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://example.com',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error!');
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**My Issue:**

Everytime I test on phonegap developer app in the console I get back

```
"Proxy error for url: http://example.com undefined"
"HPE_INVALID_CONTACT http://example.com"
```

**UPDATE**

I have just tried this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com" method="post" id="app-send" name="app-send">
    <input id="a" name="a" type="text">
    <input id="b" name="b" type="text">
    <input id="c" name="c" type="text">
    <input id="timestamp" name="timestamp" type="text">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

And this works. So how could I submit the data using AJax and stop the page from changing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using phonegap injunction of jquery mobile

You should add `data-ajax="false"` to your form element to stop the jquery mobile default behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

please try adding e.preventDefault() to stop the default behaviour

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#app-send').submit(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
             //rest of your code
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will need to whitelist your server IP. Please look in the PhoneGap documentation.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Domain Whitelisting Guide.